# How to redirect to a specific section on an aspx page but from a different aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

[image: Login.aspx]

I have created these links using asp: linkbutton, like this

```
  <li id="lhome" runat="server" class="active"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnhome" runat="server" OnClick="btnhome_Click" href="#home" PostBackUrl="~/Index.aspx">Home</asp:LinkButton></li>

  <li id="lservice" runat="server"><asp:LinkButton ID="btnservice" runat="server" href="#works" OnClick="btnservice_Click" PostBackUrl="~/Index.aspx">Services</asp:LinkButton></li>

  <li runat="server" id="llogin"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnlogin" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton></li>
```

My first page is Index.aspx which consists of home, about, services and other sections on a single page I can go to any of these sections directly from the same page. But if I am on the Login.aspx then on clicking these links just redirects me to the **Index.aspx** but not to the specific section. I tried almost everything but it didn't help.

This is my Index.aspx page:

[image: Index.aspx]

I tried using this and when clicked on Home on Login.aspx

```
        <li><a href="Index.aspx/#about">About</a></li>
```

got this result:

[image: After redirection from login.aspx]

the whole design got disturbed.

Please help how I can redirect to Services or About or other sections on Index.aspx from Login.aspx or other pages with the same header. I have created this navbar using asp.net UserControls and used it on both the pages.
I can't make my question more specific.

Please help!

Comment: How your login page must know  which section is intended?

Comment: use `<a href="Index.aspx#about">`. Without the `/`

Comment: It worked this way. Thank you..   @ VDWWD